# convert 4 bytes to 3 bytes in C++

Tags: c++

I have a requirement, where 3 bytes (24 bits) need to be populated in a binary protocol. The original value is stored in an int (32 bits). One way to achieve this would be as follows:-

Technique1:-

```
long x = 24;
long y = htonl(x);
long z = y>>8;
memcpy(dest, z, 3);
```

Please let me know if above is the correct way to do it?

The other way, which i dont understand was implemented as below

Technique2:-

```
typedef struct {
char data1;
char data2[3];
} some_data;

typedef union {
long original_data;
some_data data;
} combined_data;

long x = 24;

combined_data somedata;
somedata.original_data = htonl(x);

memcpy(dest, &combined_data.data.data2, 3);
```

What i dont understand is, how did the 3 bytes end up in combined_data.data.data2 as opposed to  first byte should go into combined_data.data.data1 and next 2 bytes should go into
combined_data.data.data2?

This is x86_64 platform running 2.6.x linux and gcc.

PARTIALLY SOLVED:-
On x86_64 platform, memory is addressed from right to left. So a variable of type long with value 24, will have following memory representation

```
|--Byte4--|--Byte3--|--Byte2--|--Byte1--|
   0          0         0        0x18
```

With htonl() performed on above long type, the memory becomes

```
|--Byte4--|--Byte3--|--Byte2--|--Byte1--|
   0x18       0         0         0
```

In the struct some_data, the

```
data1 = Byte1
data2[0] = Byte2
data2[1] = Byte3
data4[2] = Byte4
```

But my Question still holds, Why not simply right shift by 8 as shown in technique 1 ?

Comment: Probably has something to do with endianness.

Answer (score 2):

A byte takes 8 bits :-)

```
int x = 24;
int y = x<<8;
```

moving by 0 you are changing nothing. By 1 - *2, by 2 - *4, by 8 - *256.

if we are on the BIG ENDIAN machine, 4 bytes are put in memory as so: 2143. And such algorythms won't work for numbers greater than 2^15. On the other way, on the  BIG ENDIAN machine you should define, what means " putting integer in 3 bytes"

Hmm. I think, the second proposed algorythm will be ok, but change the order of bytes:

You have them as 2143. You need 321, I think. But better check it.

Edit: I checked on wiki - x86 is little endian, they say, so algorythms are OK

Comment: My understanding is that bits are numbered 0 -7 and not 1- 8. is that correct?

Comment: The '8' represents the number of bits positions you're shifting, shifting 0 will get you nothing.

Comment: @Jimm: It doesn't matter what labels the bits have.  `x<<8` will shift `x` by 8 bits.

Comment: Bit numbering is one thing and is usually 0-7 but how many bits are there?

Comment: @Griwes: Uhm, no. `operator<<` and it's counterpart takes the number of *bits* to shift.

Comment: @Griwes - Andreas is right. That's why it's called a bitwise shift operator

Comment: @AndreasMagnusson, crap, typo.

Comment: @AndreasMagnusson Operator `<<` is not `operator<<`.

Comment: @Jimm: You are correct -- bits in a byte are usually numbered 0-7. So how many bits are in a byte?

Comment: To get a byte, you have to bite 8 bits

Comment: @Pubby: Thanks, you cleared my foggy mind from the depths of confusion.

Comment: @Gangnus what is problem with technique 1? it effectively achieves same result as technique 2?

Comment: @Jimm There is no problem with technique 1. Both works on little endian machines. But the first one cannot be changed easily for big endian machines. The second one can be changed easily. That's all.